# ASP NET select object from list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner in ASP NET and I don't know how to select object from list for example I have static data in my model:

```
namespace ProjectMVC.Models
{
    public class Initializer
    {
       
        public List<Profile> GetProfiles()
        {
            var profile = new List<Profile>(){
                new Profile {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Henrik Crawford",
                    SportType = "Спортсмен",
                    Location = "Украина, Кременчуг"
                },
                new Profile {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Diane McCartney",
                    SportType = "Спортсмен",
                    Location = "Украина, Кременчуг"
                },
                new Profile {
                    Id = 4,
                    Name = "William Jenkins",
                    SportType = "Спортсмен",
                    Location = "Украина, Кременчуг"
                },
            };

            return profile;
        }
    }
```

And I have ajax request which send an Id of user. For this I have actionresult in controller:

```
namespace ProjectMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Initializer init = new Initializer();

       public ActionResult AddUserAjax(int UserId)
        {
          List<Profile> SomeList = init.GetProfiles();

// here I want to select and return user from list , where UserId == Id from list in model

           }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
var user = SomeList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == UserId)
```

It's utilising [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397926.aspx) which is very powerful for querying objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Where` or `FirstOrDefault` if you want to get one user:

```
var user = SomeList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == UserId);
```